# fluent nhibernate join vs hasmany / manytomany

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

whats the difference between using join() and using hasmany mappings to map entities.
Can I get same results using both of these features--- I would think Join() would let you think data driven way?

Answer (score 0):

Join is *completely* unrelated to one-to-many and many-to-many's. It's for composing an entity from 2 or more tables. See the [NHibernate docs on join](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-join).

Comment: how about ManyToOne using References.. Are we doing about the same thing?